# mysql function, how to refer to table field datatype

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

in MYSQL i have a myfield column in mytable table which has let's say a varchar(8) data type

```
CREATE TABLE mytable  ( 
    id      INT  NOT NULL,
    myfield VARCHAR( 8 ))
```

in a function or procedure i'd like to refer to myfield datatype, something like that:

```
DECLARE myvar mytable.myfield%TYPE
```

in alternative to explicitly declare it

```
DECLARE myvar VARCHAR( 8 )
```

Is there a way in a MYSQL function or procedure,  to refer to a column datatype when declaring variable o return type? 
thanks

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this?

Comment: hi, I'd like just a bit more type safety in my functions, I'm used to Oracle where it's possible to do that, and I'd like to know if there's a way to do it in Mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that in MySQL. DECLARE must statically declare a variable's type and size.